# Why do antidepressant drugs increase body mass?

Tags: medications, body-weight, ssri-selective-serotonin, weight-gain

Serotonin is an anorexient neurotransmitter. But if I am right, antidepressant drugs like SSRIs increase the amount of serotonin in the brain.

> So why do antidepressants increase body mass if serotonin is an anorexient?

Edit : You can find here that antidepressants are associated with weight gain :
https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/319527

https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/expert-answers/antidepressants-and-weight-gain/faq-20058127

https://www.webmd.com/depression/features/antidepressants-weight-gain#1

I also was taught that in a pharmacology class.

Edit2 : What I found is one reason is that the improvement in mood as a cause of these drugs may lead to an improvement in apetite and thus weight gain, but is this the only reason?

Comment: i have my doubts to "serotonin [being] an anorexient neurotransmitter" could you kindly reference that? in fact, fluoxetine is one among only a few that has that propriety (not all ssri). Nevertheless, regarding the links you've set available, none refer that all ssri increase  weight.. they give one example paroxetine and in this case is associated with the H1 antagonism (and thus the adverse effects).. https://go.drugbank.com/drugs/DB00715